# Laravel - Disable vite asset handling in specific folders

Tags: laravel, vite, rollupjs

I have a Laravel project with some images inside the `public/images` folder. I can load easily with a request to `https://[domain]/images/[fileName]`

I also have a Vue component built with vite that simply uses an externally available image:

```js
<template>
  ...
  <img src="/images/[fileName]" />
  ...
</template>
```

When I try to build the files with `yarn build`, I receive the following vite error:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/images/[fileName]" from "[projectRoot]/resources/js/VueComponent.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
```

I get it that Vite is trying to handle the file for me but he doesn't know where to find it in order to include it in the output folder.

How can tell Vite to simply NOT do that, and ignore asset bundling for the images paths?

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the Laravel docs, but have the newer version of Vite then you need to...

Change this:

```
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
```

To this:

```
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrlsOptions: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
```